# Google Maps API on android not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to add a map to my android application.
But I am getting the error posted below.

I have installed the google play services, and have also added
the required dependency for my app to support map.

I have added the required api key to the manifest,
added the following line after the application tag

> uses-library android:required="true"
>   android:name="com.google.android.gms"

(the following in an element of the application tag and not an attribute)
An idea what I am doing wrong?

```
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 03-12 15:31:11.457: E/AndroidRuntime(12833): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
```

Comment: From the bottom of your log: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng` This means that that class is missing, and wasn't in your app when you deployed it.  Which probably means you forgot to include the google maps API as part of your project (you do this by targetting "Google Apis Level X" instead of "Android vX.XX" in your project).

Comment: So I am using the Google Apis target. The following is what is there in my properties file - target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:16
android.library.reference.1=../../libproject/google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 0):

so I cracked this question a few days ago and here is how I made it work. I removed all traces of the google play library in the projects sections. Next I re-imported the google play library but this time I clicked the option for copying it into my workspace as well. Next in the added this library in the compile paths and it worked.