# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to develop android app  with google map API v2.and try this tutorial but i stuck with some error .which i mention at the end .

tutorial followed
[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.bushunter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final LatLng HMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("kiel")
                .snippet("kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HMBURG, 15));

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bushunter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.bushunter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.bushunter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAL1CFSYV5jjCcG5Cj-BEQ5KprLBXZ5n4c" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bushunter.MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and found following error .plz help

```
 04-14 13:20:58.880: E/dalvikvm(16036): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng', referenced from method com.example.bushunter.MainActivity.<clinit>
04-14 13:20:58.880: W/dalvikvm(16036): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 448 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng;) in Lcom/example/bushunter/MainActivity;
04-14 13:20:58.880: D/dalvikvm(16036): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/dalvikvm(16036): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment', referenced from method com.example.bushunter.MainActivity.onCreate
04-14 13:20:58.890: W/dalvikvm(16036): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 445 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment;) in Lcom/example/bushunter/MainActivity;
04-14 13:20:58.890: D/dalvikvm(16036): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0014
04-14 13:20:58.890: D/dalvikvm(16036): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0db1 at 0x0c in Lcom/example/bushunter/MainActivity;.<clinit>
04-14 13:20:58.890: D/dalvikvm(16036): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0db1 at 0x1d in Lcom/example/bushunter/MainActivity;.<clinit>
04-14 13:20:58.890: D/dalvikvm(16036): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0db2 at 0x20 in Lcom/example/bushunter/MainActivity;.onCreate
04-14 13:20:58.890: D/dalvikvm(16036): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0db2 at 0x37 in Lcom/example/bushunter/MainActivity;.onCreate
04-14 13:20:58.890: W/dalvikvm(16036): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/bushunter/MainActivity;
04-14 13:20:58.890: W/dalvikvm(16036): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/bushunter/MainActivity;)
04-14 13:20:58.890: D/AndroidRuntime(16036): Shutting down VM
04-14 13:20:58.890: W/dalvikvm(16036): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41838da0)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036): Process: com.example.bushunter, PID: 16036
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at com.example.bushunter.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:17)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
04-14 13:20:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16036):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you added the `Google Maps library` to your project?

Comment: Add google-play-services-lib library project to your project build path. Also add google-play-services.jar to your project's lib folder.

Comment: Sorry i did not mention but i have already imported the library.

Comment: Just check that the library is marked as a green color.

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun i have added both the .jar and the library file but still getting the same error .

Comment: @PiyushGupta i have checked but there is no green color on library.

Comment: Thats means ur library is not integrated properly. You need to enable `"Copy to Workspace"` checkbox while import that library project.

Comment: @PiyushGupta i have done that too still the same error .

Comment: Then just remove jar file. Clean your project and run it. If you have added a jar file too then just enable check box for that jar file in `Order and Export Menu` option.

Comment: I think the solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370641/google-maps-api-on-android-not-working